# How can I delete all records associated with a "User"?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using Entity Framework along with the default ASP.NET Membership service.  I also have a 3rd table for "profile information".  I thought EF would take care of all that internally but it does not.  When I attempt to delete a user by going to a URL like `http://localhost:19506/User/Delete/SomeGUIDhere` I get some nasty errors related to the fact that there are foreign key constraints in place.

How can these types of dependencies be managed?  Having to keep track of it all kind of defeats the purpose of EF so I'm guessing I'm missing something minor.

*EDIT* to include some code I have that is working.  I still want to know if there is a better way than what I have below.  Seems like it would get out of control really quickly with lots of foreign key dependencies floating around.

```
public void DeleteUser(User u)
{
    db.Profiles.DeleteObject(u.Profile);
    db.aspnet_Membership.DeleteObject(u.aspnet_Membership);
    db.Users.DeleteObject(u);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can these types of dependencies be
>   managed? Having to keep track of it
>   all kind of defeats the purpose of EF
>   so I'm guessing I'm missing something
>   minor.

Unfortunately this is still a manual process, and two-fold as @Danny Varod pointed out:

1. In your database, assuming the foreign key relationship has already been established, make sure that the condition "On Delete -> Cascade" is selected. You can change this in SQL Server Management Studio.
2. In you EF entity model you also should designate this option on the relationship. For this just select the dotted line between the entities that represents the relationship. In the properties you will see the appropriate option for "Cascading Delete" - you should pick delete for the End that has the **1** and not the *.

[image]

Comment: Seems simple enough.  In your screenshot, does the highlighted part mean that when you delete a post all its associated comments will go with it?  In my question, I have a 1:1 user:profile.  When I delete a user I want the profile to go also but I don't want to be able to accidentally delete profiles if the user isn't being deleted.

Comment: @Pete: Yes your statement is correct - actually on checking up this issue - Assuming you are doing Database first EF should have picked up the cascading delete from the DB - make sure you make the setting there, remove the entity from your model, and re-add it by "updating from database" - it should add the cascading delete then - please reconfirm in your model afterwards. Also check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/08/19/tip-33-how-cascade-delete-really-works-in-ef.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Cascade delete on relationships of conceptual model (and db).

Comment: If I knew how to make use of the cascading deletes with my entity models and on the database I wouldn't have posted the question.  Do you atleast have some pseudocode on how I can rewrite my code to not have to worry about dependencies?

Comment: I believe you can alter the relationship, and set the delete type to casacade

Comment: In the edmx design, select the relationship, in the properties toolwindow, change End1/2 On Delete to Cascade.